# Styling specific words in JavaFX's TextArea

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

Given some text with tags, for example:

```
He saw <person>Alice</person> in <location>London</location> the other day.
```

How could we apply style to specific tags in JavaFX. For example, we might want to have all *person*-tagged words to be blue or all *location*-tagged words to be bold.

More specifically consider the following code:

```
TextArea content = new TextArea();
content.setText("He saw <person>Alice</person> in ...");
```

which is displayed in the GUI. How could we change the style of the tagged words?

In the JavaFX stylesheet I've tried adding:

```
.text-area .content person{
    -fx-color:blue;
}
```

But that doesn't work. Perhaps there is another way of approaching this entire problem?